# Changing a Worksheet Formula to a VBA formula with worksheet.function

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

currently I have a relatively complex workbook formula, which I would like to translate to a vba formula.

Currently, I wrote the following but I want it to basically evaluate the function during code execution and insert the value into the required cell.

I imagine this is some combination of `worksheetfunction` but I am unsure of how to translate this

Code (doesnt work)

```
MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value = WorksheetFunction.SUMIFS(mws.range(N:N),mws.Range(B:B),worksheetfunction.INDEX(mws.range(B:B),worksheetfunction.MAX(worksheetfunction.INDEX((mws.range(C:C)=MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC - 1))*worksheetfunction.ROW(mws.range(C:C)),0))),mws.range(C:C),MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC - 1))
```

Excel Formula

`=SUMIFS($N:$N,$B:$B,INDEX($B:$B,MAX(INDEX(($C:$C=$AM41)*ROW($C:$C),0))),$C:$C,$AM41)`

MWS is a worksheet
LastMWSR is the last row in the Worksheet
CLASTMWSC is the last column in the worksheet

Appreciate your thoughts

EDIT: with another attempt at the formula

Comment: You can start [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/worksheetfunction-object-excel)

Comment: Not what I asked, asked how to do it through worksheet.function so its evaluated in the code and just a formula pasted to a cell.

I'm looking for if need to specify address or Range properties preceding formulas or if I need to use R1C1 notation, as well as if I need to clarify my dynamic ranges. There is a lot more to this, than that article covers.

Comment: Dear friend, 
for using `Application.worksheetfunction` you need to pass the range and argument in VBA. For instance `N:N` should be something like `range("n:n")` anyway, Lot of time by using VBA level codes you have option to do what you are looking for in a different and more easier way. You have lots of typo, I will edit your post, but remember for all the functions you have to use the worksheetfunction again!

`MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value = worksheetfunction.SumIfs(nws.range("n:n"),nws.range("b:b"),worksheetfunction.Index(range("b:b"),application.Max(....)`

Comment: Another option is to get what you are looking for is to put the formula in the cell, then follow up with `MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value = MWS.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value`.  This will replace the formula with the value.

Answer (score 2):

Three issues here

1. Invalid worksheet references `mws.Range(...`
2. missing quotes `Range(B:B)`
3. bad bracketing

Refactored, and adding some reductionist variables

```
Dim mws As Worksheet
Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
Dim mwsN As Range
Dim mwsC As Range
Dim mwsB As Range
Dim mwsLast As Range

Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
Set mws = Worksheets("mws")
Set mwsN = mws.Range("N:N")
Set mwsC = mws.Range("C:C")
Set mwsB = mws.Range("B:B")
Set mwsLast = mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC - 1)

mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value = _
  wf.SumIfs(mwsN, mwsB, wf.Index(mwsB, wf.Max(wf.Index((mwsC = mwsLast) * wf.Row(mwsC), 0))), mwsC, mwsLast)
```

Comment: Hey Chris, I can see where I went wrong with this, and your code looks sensible, but in practice it is still throwing a mismatch error when I go run it. "Run-Time error 13: Type Mismatch" Not sure where the error would be as everything appears correctly defined. Any tips?