# Appropriate Definitions on a Mismatch Error VBA

Tags: vba, excel

Hello this is an expansion, on a previous question asked [Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50748794/changing-a-worksheet-formula-to-a-vba-formula-with-worksheet-function)

Currently I am trying to take a complex excel formula and convert into a application.worksheetfunction VBA process so it's evaluated during code execution.

The biggest issue now is that I am coming across a Mismatch error, post all my definitions. Is it evident to anyone why this would be attracting a mismatch error?

```
    Dim mws As Worksheet
    Dim wf As WorksheetFunction
    Dim mwsN As Range
    Dim mwsC As Range
    Dim mwsB As Range
    Dim mwsLast As Range

    Set wf = Application.WorksheetFunction
    Set mws = Sheets("Marks")
    Set mwsN = mws.Range("N:N")
    Set mwsC = mws.Range("C:C")
    Set mwsB = mws.Range("B:B")
    LastMWSR = mws.Cells(mws.Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row
    ClastMWSC = mws.Cells(1, mws.Columns.Count).End(xlToLeft).Column
    Set mwsLast = mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC - 1)


    'error, is thrown just below this line

    mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, ClastMWSC).Value = _
    wf.SumIfs(mwsN, mwsB, wf.Index(mwsB, wf.Max(wf.Index((mwsC = mwsLast) * wf.Row(mwsC), 0))), mwsC, mwsLast)
```

EDIT:

For simplicity please see the excel formula being replicated

```
=SUMIFS($N:$N,$B:$B,INDEX($B:$B,MAX(INDEX(($C:$C=$AM41)*ROW($C:$C),0))),$C:$C,$AM41)
```

EDIT2: here is another attempt at the same problem. This way I would insert the formula calculate it then paste as values, though it is still throwing a mismatch error.

```
mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, CLastMWSC).Formula = "=SUMIFS(" & mws.Range("N:N").Address & "," & mws.Range("B:B").Address & ",INDEX(" & mws.Range("B:B").Address & ",MAX(INDEX((" & mws.Range("C:C").Address & "=" & mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, CLastMWSC - 1).Address & "*ROW(" & Range("C:C").Address & ",0)))," & mws.Range("C:C") & "," & mws.Cells(LastMWSR + 1, CLastMWSC - 1).Address & ")"
```

Comment: Write `Option Explicit` and try to debug your code and declare everything. What is the idea of `Index((mwsC = mwsLast)`?

Comment: Which line is causing the error?

Comment: It's the line that is actually executing the worksheet functions @Mistella

Comment: @Vityata Index((mwsC = mwsLast) searches a particular column (C:C) for a certain position ID (which would be identified in mwsLast)

Comment: Syntax is for sure wrong. The part `(mwsC = mwsLast)` evaluates to a boolean and not a range. Do you mean something like  `Index(mwsC, mwsLast)`?

Comment: @Funthomas I expect that portion of the fomula to essentially read like this when compared back to excel (INDEX(($C:$C=$AM41). By chance are you able to suggest how it should read?

Comment: Are you sure? I would think it is INDEX($C:$C, $AM41) - but not really familiar with the `Index` function

Comment: Sorry @FunThomas to be clear the full section of that formula reads like this. INDEX(($C:$C=$AN41)*ROW($C:$C),0). The first part defines exactly what I am looking for in the array, so basically in conjunction with the Max function, I am looking for the last row where $AM41 appears.

Comment: Why not just use `Evaluate("your_working_formula")`.  I'd also suggest accomplishing your goal using VBA functions working on a VBA array. See the late Chip Pearson's web site article on [VBA Arrays and Worksheet Ranges](http://www.cpearson.com/Excel/ArraysAndRanges.aspx)

Comment: @RonRosenfeld haven't wrote an array before and I'm not familiar with Evaluate. Would I be able to do that with a dynamic variable range?

Comment: If your formula works on the worksheet, it should work using `Evaluate`.  Plenty of resources on the 'net about using it. In your `worksheetfunction`, this:  `mwsC = mwsLast` is where your `Type Mismatch` is coming from.  In VBA you can't compare a `range` with a `long` to return an array.  So far as using VBA arrays, it is an exceedingly useful tool, and can often increase the speed of a VBA procedure by an order of magnitude.

Comment: So you are suggesting I turn MwsC = MWSLast into a an array before I insert it into the formula? Might be beyond my current abilities. Do you believe something like my most recent Edit might work?

Comment: You don't need to do that if you use `Evaluate`. On the other hand, if you are going to create a vba array, read the reference I provided and loop through the array to do your testing and get your results.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld are you able to provide an example of how I should be using the evaluate function in this case?

Comment: `your worksheet cell = Evaluate("=SUMIFS($N:$N,$B:$B,INDEX($B:$B,MAX(INDEX(($C:$C=$AM41)*ROW($C:$C),0))),$C:$C,$AM41)")`  You just create a string to Evaluate.